# Java Jung draw ovals

Tags: java, geometry, jung

i am using jung (java) try to draw circles to the Background. I dont get any output and wondering  why it is not working.

Iam using PreRenderPaintable and PostRenderPaintable but still get no results.

```
        vv.addPreRenderPaintable(new VisualizationViewer.Paintable() {

        public void paint(Graphics g) 
        {
               System.out.println("PRE RENDER");
               System.out.println("vv.getComponentCount()= " + vv.getComponentCount());

            Graphics2D      g2d         = (Graphics2D)g;
            AffineTransform oldXform    = g2d.getTransform();
            AffineTransform lat         = vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().getTransformer(Layer.LAYOUT).getTransform();
            AffineTransform vat         = vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().getTransformer(Layer.VIEW).getTransform();
            AffineTransform at          = new AffineTransform();
            at.concatenate(g2d.getTransform());
            at.concatenate(vat);
            at.concatenate(lat);
            g2d.setTransform(at);

            g.drawOval(100, 100, 150, 150);

            g.drawString("adsadd", 200, 200);

            g2d.setTransform(oldXform);
        }

        public boolean useTransform() { return false; }
    });

vv.addPostRenderPaintable(new VisualizationViewer.Paintable()
    {
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            System.out.println("POST RENDER");
            System.out.println("vv.getComponentCount()= " + vv.getComponentCount());
            Component comp = vv.getComponent(0);
            System.out.println(comp);
            System.out.println(comp.getClass());

            g.drawString("adasasdsadasdsadsadasdasdsadd", 300, 300);
        }

        public boolean useTransform() 
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you get any exception ? if so please post the stacktrace..

Comment: i dont get any exceptions.. only this output: PRE RENDER
vv.getComponentCount()= 1
POST RENDER
vv.getComponentCount()= 1
javax.swing.CellRendererPane[,0,0,0x0,hidden]
class javax.swing.CellRendererPane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was not setting the color of the output.
For Example:

```
  g.setFont(font);
  Color oldColor = g.getColor();
  g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
```